# Multiple domain SSL certificate: do I need to hold the property of all domains?

Tags: ssl-certificate, domain

I just bought a multiple domains SSL certificate from godaddy.com for (an example):

```
site1.my-company.com
```

and

```
site2.your-company.com
```

both domains point to the same IP address. I hold the property of the first domain (my-company.com, the registrant data is the same I used to request the SSL certificate).

I do not hold the property of the second domine (your-company.com) **but I have a full manage of it (without changing the owner data)**

Do you think GoDaddy will reject my request for the second Subject Alternative Names (SAN) by checking the whois data ?

Comment: Is a first post for me here, please comment the downvote. Many thanks.

Comment: Just a suggestion, about your infrastructure (not part of the question but anyway) you should use SNI module, (rather than SANs) of your web server if you host multiple domaine on the same shared target.

Comment: @DrI Not an option if you have users on Windows XP, though.

Comment: I simply follow the instructions provided by GoDaddy and I never saw something regarding the use of SNI.

Comment: @ceejayoz gloup, didn't noticed that :'(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get an SSL certificate for a domain you do not control. This is part of the fundamental point of SSL. GoDaddy will require you to verify ownership of the domain by sending a verification e-mail to the owner of `your-company.com`.

Without this sort of verification, I could get an SSL cert for Google, PayPal, etc., rendering SSL's protections against man-in-the-middle attacks entirely useless.

Comment: I can full manage the you-company.com domain but I can't change the owner data.

Comment: I can respond to email for confirmation...

Comment: The verification e-mail will go to the owner of the domain per the WHOIS record.